# Is it necessary to use getters in hashcode implementation in Hibernate for Proxy objects?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I know for equals method implementation should be like this to avoid problems in case of Hibernate returns of proxy objects.

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
   if (this == o) return true;
   if (!(o instanceof Parent)) return false;

   Parent parent = (Parent) o;

   return getName() != null ? getName().equals(parent.getName()) : parent.getName() == null;
}
```

- I need to use `instanceof`. (If I compare like `getClass() != o.getClass()` it will always true for proxy object o)
- I must use getters to load proxy object, otherwise field will be `null`.

But I also want to know if it is true for `hashcode` implementation should I use getters considering proxy objects?

Should I implement like this:

```java
public int hashCode() {
   return getName().hashCode();
}
```

Or is it okay to implement like this too:

```java
public int hashCode() {
   return name.hashCode();
}
```

Note: Suppose that name is non-null field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate documentation [says](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-pojo):

> Applications that wish to remain portable across JPA providers should adhere to these requirements:
>
> ...
>
> The persistent state of an entity is represented by instance variables, which may correspond to JavaBean-style properties. *An instance variable must be directly accessed only from within the methods of the entity by the entity instance itself.* The state of the entity is available to clients only through the entity’s accessor methods (getter/setter methods) or other business methods.
>
> Hibernate, however, is not as strict in its requirements. The differences from the list above include:
>
> ...
>
> *Hibernate does not restrict the application developer from exposing instance variables and referencing them from outside the entity class itself.* The validity of such a paradigm, however, is debatable at best.

And [further](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-pojo-accessors):

> Attributes (whether fields or getters/setters) need not be declared public. *Hibernate can deal with attributes declared with the public, protected, package or private visibility. Again, if wanting to use runtime proxy generation for lazy loading, the getter/setter should grant access to at least package visibility.*

So, I do not see any restrictions for instance variable access inside an entity. But, in any case, I would suggest you to use consistent approach for `equals/hashCode` implementation.